# C any bit in the least significant byte of x equals 1

Tags: c

I have to write an expression that will return `1` if `any bit in the least significant byte of k equals 1`

I cannot use any logical operators.

To mask the least significant bit we use

```
(x & 0xFF);
```

How can I return `0` or `1` without logical operators if the above is true?

Comment: Does `!` count as a "logical operator"?

Comment: I don't believe ternary will count. !, I believe should be ok.

Comment: Why would ```!``` be OK if logical operators are not OK?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution with nothing looking even vaguely like a logical operator:

```
((unsigned char)k + 255) / 256
```

Comment: Not as flashy as @dasblinkenlight's example, but still a keeper.

Comment: this doesn't use logical operators and it should be considered as the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a common trick to force any non-zero value to `1`, while keeping zeros in place:

```
return !!(x & 0xFF);
```

This evaluates to zero if and only if `x & 0xFF` is zero; otherwise, this evaluates to `1`.

There is also a far uglier expression that avoids logical operators altogether:

```
return ((x>>0)|(x>>1)|(x>>2)|(x>>3)|(x>>4)|(x>>5)|(x>>6)|(x>>7)) & 1;
```

Comment: Can this be accomplished without this trick? Or, is this really the only possible solution?

Comment: @ChaceFields Well, there's another one, but it's not nearly as cute.

Comment: the `!!` solution should also be faster as it should be two instructions whereas the other involves 7 `|` and 7 `>>`s (the first is unnecessary) and of course they both involve a single `&`. I would say the `!` *is* a logical operator, though this 'no logical ops' restriction smells like a homework restriction.

Comment: `!` is a logical operator: "The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, ..." C11 6.5.3.3 , bit if OP likes all is OK

Comment: @Steven Lu Many a compiler will optimize `!!` into no more instructions the `!`. :)

Comment: @chux OP [said in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106477/c-any-bit-in-the-least-significant-byte-of-x-equals-1/19106491?noredirect=1#comment28250517_19106477) that it was OK: "`!`, I believe should be ok."

Comment: !, & and | are logical operators. it is not an answer to OPs question.

Comment: @V-X First, `|` is **not** a logical operator, it's a bitwise operator; second, OP has explicitly said that `!` is OK - I asked him before posting my answer.

Comment: Aw. I see. It is called bitwise operator and therefore is not called logical. Ok. I'll shut up.

Answer (score 2):

No logical operators

```
// A little sneaky on the "No logical operators" part
int AnyLSBit8Set_switch(int x) {
  unsigned char ch = (unsigned char) x;
  switch (ch) {
    case 0: return 0;
  }
return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@rici's is good.  If you don't want to have to use the (unsigned char) cast:

```
((((x%256)+256)%256)+255)/256
```

Comment: Do you need the `+256` part to dealing with `signed`?

Comment: @chux: I think that's correct. If `x` is negative, C (99) requires `/` to truncate towards 0, so `x%256` will be in the range [-255,0]. Adding 256 and modding again normalizes to the value arrived at with the cast to unsigned char; i.e. mod with positive modulus. +1 for making at least two of us think.

Comment: Yes, I learned that trick to deal with modulo of a negative number a long time ago (it bugs me that C doesn't default to the result of a modulo always being non-negative--that's almost always what I want when I use modulo).  It does make the expression a bit complicated.

Comment: @willus: The cool thing is that gcc also knows that trick, so your solution and my solution compile to exactly the same code (`movzbl %dil, %eax / addl $255, %eax / sarl $8, %eax / ret`)

Comment: gcc is the best tool ever made.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If k is an integral type, I do believe this would work: `k-((k>>8)<<8)`

Just for fun, here's another one you can use:

```
bool lsb_non_zero(int k)
{
    //for little endian, use this
    return *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&k));
    //for big endian, use this
    // return *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&k +sizeof(int) -1));
}
```

OR, again, just for the heck of it....

```
#include<boost/detail/endian.hpp>
bool lsb_non_zero(int k)
{
    #if defined BOOST_LITTLE_ENDIAN
    return *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&k));
    #elif defined BOOST_BIG_ENDIAN
    return *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&k +sizeof(int) -1));
    #endif
}
```

Comment: That's just `k%256`, isn't it? (Leaving aside the fact that `k>>8` is implementation-defined if `k` is negative.)

Comment: Yeah :) It is. You're also right about the results when negative.